# freenect2 impl failed to open kinect v2 processing

Tags: processing, kinect, openkinect

I have managed to get the Kinect to be recognized by my PC, it has the right drivers installed and shows up in Microsoft Kinect Studio. However it still doesn’t show up in Processing

I've installed the drivers using the Microsoft guide, all the necessary libraries in processing. I've tried it in processing v2 and 3.
The kinect (1520) works and is recognized in Kinect studio but processing just will not find it!! I’ve searched every forum out there but nobody is having this problem!

Can you help. This is driving me insane????????

http://imgur.com/jR9Y3OV

Comment: Which version of the Kinect V2 Processing library are you using ?

Comment: Open Kinect for processing 1.0

Comment: Found this note on the [repository](https://github.com/ThomasLengeling/KinectPV2): *For Processing 2.2.1 please use the [KinectPV2 0.7.2 version](https://github.com/ThomasLengeling/KinectPV2/releases/tag/0.7.2)*. Might be worth a shot

Comment: Brilliant this works!! I am trying to use it with a tutorial from a Moullinex music video

http://moullinex.tumblr.com/post/3180520798/catalina-music-video

I have altered the script to work with processing 3 by using the PV2 library instead of the openkinect but it keeps coming up with "cannot find a class or type named vector", when i change this to PVector it comes back with "PVector is not generic it cannot be parametrised with arguments <object>"

Can you see a soloution?

http://imgur.com/AxO1i6R

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RvLhh2z7

Comment: Check out my answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

The notes on the [library's repository notes](https://github.com/ThomasLengeling/KinectPV2) mentions:

> For Processing 2.2.1 please use the [KinectPV2 0.7.2 version](https://github.com/ThomasLengeling/KinectPV2/releases/tag/0.7.2)

Regarding the Vector error, that is a [java.util.Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) (which is like an array with dynamic size (can have elements added/removed at runtime easily)).

I recommend leaving this line as is:

```
Vector <Object> recording = new Vector<Object>();
```

without getting PVector involved but you also need to add the import for the Vector class at the top of your sketch:

```
import java.util.Vector;
```

(Previous versions of Processing had java.util.* imported by default, but later versions removed these imports which is why older sketches usually need these java.util related imports added in the sketch)

**Update**

I see a source of confusion here. There two Kinect v2 Processing wrappers with contributions from the same person:

1. [KinectPV2](https://github.com/ThomasLengeling/KinectPV2)
2. [OpenKinect for Processing](https://github.com/shiffman/OpenKinect-for-Processing)

**KinectPV2** uses the Microsoft Kinect SDK behind the scenes. This worked with your setup since you installed the Microsoft Kinect SDK.

**OpenKinect for Processing** uses a different driver: [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2).
To use this library you need to also install the libfreenect2 driver after installing the Kinect SDK, as mentioned on the [repository notes](https://github.com/shiffman/OpenKinect-for-Processing):

> Kinect v2 additional software
>
> For Windows 8, Follow the the [installation of the libusk driver](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2#libusbk-driver). First
>   install the Kinect v2 Windows SDK then change the USB 3.0 drivers
>   properties to libusbK using Zadig.

Regarding the `getDepthFPS()` error, this error means that the kinect instance you're using does not have this function you're trying to call. That is why Processing 3 marks it in red, same as `getRawDepth()` lower. Why is this happening though ? The code you started from used the OpenKinect for Processing wrapper (which didn't work for you before, but may work if you install the libfreenect2 driver). The functions of these library are different. 
(Compare the code from **Examples > Contributed Libraries** on both libraries to get a feel for this).

Where does this leave you at the moment ?
You have two choices:

1. Install the libfreenect2 driver as advised and try the OpenKinect for Processing library again. If it works, the syntax from the Moulinex video should be similar
2. Stick to the KinectV2 library you're using, but check out it's [reference](http://codigogenerativo.com/code/kinectpv2-k4w2-processing-library/) to find the equivalent function names from your existing code.

Comment: Thanks. I read something similar somewhere else but your answer is much more consice. I have another issue though

I'm getting the function "getdepthFPS" does not exist

I can't find an equivalent command in the Kinect PV2 library?

http://imgur.com/H2KHRe6

Comment: I've updated the answer above. Feel free to vote and or mark the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Thank you, this is unbelievably helpful. I can't upvote anything until I have a reputation rating of 15. But I will when I can!